# HttpSecurity configuration - permit all still requires basic auhthentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying to add an unsecured controller endpoint `/foo/bar` to my application, but whenever I try calling it, I get `401 Unauthorized`.

Here's my `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`:

```
http
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/foo/**").permitAll()
    .and()
    .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
    .and()
    .requestMatchers()
        .antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize", "/oauth/confirm_access")
    .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
```

Would somone kindly point out what am I missing?

Comment: /foo/bar should be permitted for GET or POST or both?

Comment: @Sanj it shouldnt matter for the authentification mechanism, the methods are filtered out by the RequestMapping

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Concatenate multiple `antMatchers` in one `authorizeRequests` section:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/foo/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what's the `hierarchy` in your `config` but it doesn't seem right.

try:

```
http
    .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/foo/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
```